# How to share my android app with facebook?

Tags: android

I am very new to android development, now i am developing an app in android which needs to be
share with the social network like facebook but i haven't got any clue that how to take this step, i hope i can get a proper solution for my doubt.

Thanks,
Balaram.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by sharing?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to take a look at the Facebook API: http://developers.facebook.com/

Answer (score 1):

Start with Facebook Android SDK at [Github](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk) & download sdk (sample is included ) & follow the steps. hope it will help :)